# How to quit AWS Cli edit mode in Linux terminal and send command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I know this is a rather simple question but I am not able to find the answer I am looking for in any of the documentation.
I am using the Linux terminal to formulate an AWS command. After the command I have to specify the config via JSON.

`Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:`

So I am writing the JSON and want to trigger the command but whenever I press <kbd>enter</kbd> it only gives me a new line. I tried a lot to quit the edit mode and send the command like [Escape][quit][:q][exit][.exit]...

I am not using a specific text editor in the terminal.
Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post the output of `echo $EDITOR` so we know which editor you are using?

Comment: Try using Ctrl+D to send an end of transmission character after your JSON is complete. Here is a link to the Wikipedia page for more detail - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Ctrl+D to send an end of transmission character after your JSON is complete (and you have exited your text editor - assuming that you are typing it that way since you tried :q)

Here is a link to the Wikipedia page for more detail - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character